# Hard number theory problems that can be easily solved using algebraic geometry techniques

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'm very interested in number theory, but it happens that now I'm taking an Algebraic Geometry course.

I was wondering what kind of number-theoretic problems could be easily solved using some skills and machinery from the algebro geometer theory.

Comment: Diophantine equations that involve elliptic curves, e.g solve in $\mathbb{Z}$, $ y^2 = x^4 -3x^3+5x^2-8$.

Comment: Well, lots of number theoretic problems involve algebraic geometry (most famously everything around elliptic curves), but at some point you're going to have to input number theory per se, since results will be specific to "arithmetic fields" like number fields.

Comment: What makes a problem "hard" if it can be easily solved?

Answer (score 5):

I am not completely sure how to read the "hard" and the "easily" in your question, but as a starter you may consider the following (well-known) proposition.

*There are infinitely many non-equivalent pythagorean triples.*

This can be proven really easily (a brilliant high school student will understand the argument) observing that the set of inequivalent pythagorean triples is basically in one-to-one correspondence with the set of points with rational coordinates in the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the latter set is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of lines with rational slopes through the point $(1,0)$.

This is a basic application of the (geometric!) fact that a non-singular conic is isomorphic to the projective line, with a bit of arithmetic thrown in.

Answer (score -1):

The most crazy example: Fermat's crazy Theorem.

Comment: Does this count as "easily"?

Comment: @Mathmo123 that's a matter of taste anyway